# Skylake Intel 530 + 960m equals 100% fan usage on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: intel-graphics, asus, 16.04

I just bought a new laptop, the Asus ROG 501jw with the Skylake i7 6700HQ + Intel graphics 530 and the Nvidia 960m. When running Ubuntu 16.04 the fans runs at 100% constantly when using the intel graphics, while there seems to be no problems when using the Nvidia proprietary driver. Is this a kernel related issue? Should I wait it out or is there a fix for this here and now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laptop freezes after connecting external monitor, since 16.04 update](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762373/laptop-freezes-after-connecting-external-monitor-since-16-04-update)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here on Asus Zenbook Pro UX501VW (same GPU and CPU, Ubuntu 16.04). After I changed "quiet splash" in grub to
`acpi_osi=! acpi_backlight=native idle=nomwait`
the fan stopped spinning like mad and integrated GPU seems to work.

But now the system fails to shutdown normally and also hangs on executing glxinfo command.
Actually I don't quite understand what this line in grub means, but it was supposed to fix Fn+f5/f6 brightness buttons, which it does)

Answer (score 1):

I have the ROG G501vw (same CPU and GPU) and I had the same problem in any distro I tested.
I solved it by disabling Nouveau, just add `nouveau.modeset=0` to your grub kernel boot parameters.
I tested this on other distros such as KDE Neon and Antergos and works fine (If you add it to the LiveCD options, it also solves the problem of it freezing on the splash screen).

In case you don't know how, add it to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`

This is how mine looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=! acpi_backlight=native idle=nomwait nouveau.modeset=0"
```

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same CPU and GPU and the same issue, I posted a similar question about this issue. From what I've read sky lake CPU's are not supported fully yet.

Comment: Figured the same - i thinks it's the intel 530 acting up. Guess the only thing to do is wait for kernel updates :(

Comment: I updated the kernel to 4.5 on Ubuntu 15.10 weeks ago and still no different :(

Comment: Damn :/ maybe in 16.04.1? Dont know about kernel the update schedule. Might be fixed by then - not gonna install until it works :/

Comment: I also had another issue, not only did the fans start going on 100% full speed but after about a minute the laptop would just shut it self down.

Comment: Damn - currently i cant even get my laptop to boot with 16.04... It freezes during boot :(

Comment: unfortunately like you said before the only thing to do is wait, unless you can fix the problem yourself :|

Comment: Yeah i will try again at the next .1 release. (16.04.1)

Comment: Fedora 23 worked fine on my laptop as I recall